# Storing one bit of information in user space

Tags: scripting, programming

I'm writing a program that collects network data. I need to store one bit of information, a simple yes/no, somewhere so another process may read it. I have several options: writing a 1 or 0 to a file, `touch`ing / `rm`ing a file, writing a field into a database table, etc. There may be other ways that I am not aware of.  What is the most elegant solution in this case? This program stores no other data, it only puts out an alert under certain conditions. Performance or ease of coding is no issue. Bonus points if your solution still works if I change my mind and make it two bits.

Comment: What is the relation of the producer to the consumer? How often will the producer update the data? How long is the data valid for? How often will the consumer access the data?

Comment: This sounds like a question that might be better off on SO...

Comment: @John both reading and writing occur every couple of minutes.

Comment: The question arises why you have to write a yes/no somewhere. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Is there one read per write? Or can there be multiple reads in between writes, or multiple writes in between reads?

Comment: Currently there is 1 read per write, but I foresee many more reads per write in the future as other processes need the info.

Comment: @FloHimself the yes/no is the outcome of the processing of a network scan, stored in a file that is refreshed every couple of minutes. Other processes will not have access to that file (or to the network, for that matter).

Comment: We can migrate this to SO but it's going to get either rejected or closed as too broad. In it's current form it needs more details.

Answer (score 3):

Inter process communication isn't a small question. There is a lot of "it depends" in there. Perl has a whole chapter on the subject under [`perlipc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

However for your scenario as described - I'd write a state file, `flock` it and then write your data there.

The `flock` ensures you don't have a race condition, and the file can be of arbitrary length. You can use filesystem permissions to grant access as is suitable for your needs.

Comment: I was about to say, use a semaphore. I use to use it to pass counter from C to perl.

Comment: @Archemar wouldn't a semaphore be discarded at reboot? Otherwise, it does sound what I am looking for.

Comment: many process are discarded by reboot as a rule. can you app compute initial value after a reboot, expected or not, after a downtime of few minutes, or few days ?

Comment: @Archemar yes, that is an idea. The expected value at boot time is "yes" so it's safe to store that until the network scan has run again. Thanks.

Comment: @Archemar You should probably add that as an answer.

Comment: Every couple of minute is a long time for a computer. Write result to a file. Unless concurent/multiple paralell write, do not bother with semamhore.